# Facebook4j - Tried accessing nonexisting field user_photos node user

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I am using Facebook4j and when I try to connect the first time with my facebook account I have now :

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: message - &#40;#100&#41;
 Tried accessing nonexisting field &#40;user_photos&#41; on node type &#40;User&#41;\ncode - 100\
```

I don't know why but I don't use user_photos it's strange..

I do this

```
FacebookUtility facebookUtility = new FacebookUtility();
User userFb = facebookUtility.getFacebookUser(String.valueOf(idFb));
```

and my function getFacebookUser is :

```
public facebook4j.User getFacebookUser(String userId)  throws FacebookException{
//        Instanciate Facebook4j Facebook object to request Facebook Graph API 
        Facebook facebook = setFacebookConnector();

//        Construct Facebook4j Reading object to define Facebook Graph API reading options 
        Reading reading = setFacebookReading();

//        Instanciate Facebook4j User object to store user information         
        User userFb = facebook.getUser(userId, reading);

        return userFb;
    }
```

Comment: `user_photos` is a permission, not a field.

Comment: I don't ask for it : facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_likes", "user_events", "user_location"]

Comment: If you were asking for it at that point, that would be fine (because those are the permissions asked for during login.) But you get the message that it is not a field on the user object, so it must somehow occur in your API request that fetches the user details. Try a search for `user_photos` across the whole code base in your IDE, and see if it has slipped in some other place where it doesn’t belong.

Comment: I added the field but I still have the same error :(

Comment: It is _not_ a field.

Comment: I put it in ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_likes", "user_events", "user_location"]  i accepted after login fb and I still have the same error. I will look at the code

Comment: Ok i just found a line with that in my IDE I removed it and it works ! thank you